nginx returning 404 for resources requested via proxy_pass, but not root document
I have a problem with nginx proxy_pass not passing asset requests [css, js, fonts, etc] to the upstream server. Details about my configuration are below.
I have the following configuration for nginx on my application server set up:

upstream webapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:10000;
}


server {
    server_name wma.xxxxx.io;
    include includes/_general.conf;

    location / {

       access_log /var/log/nginx/webapp/access.log upstream_logging;
       error_log  /var/log/nginx/webapp/error.log warn;

       proxy_pass http://webapp/;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#      proxy_redirect http://$host:10000 https://$http_host;
       #index index.html;
    }

    listen 5555;

}


Now, when I navigate to the url http://wma.xxxxx.io, the page /loads/ - but none of the resources associated with it, do. So, no css, no js files, etc.
When I request a document from the server that is behind the proxy, it works:
root@appserver [/etc/nginx/sites-enabled] # curl -I http://localhost:10000/service-worker.js
HTTP/1.0 200 Document follows
Date: Fri, 9 Aug 2024 05:54:45 GMT
Server: MiniServ
Content-type: application/javascript
Last-Modified: Wed, 24 Jul 2024 04:58:46 GMT
Expires: Fri, 16 Aug 2024 05:54:45 GMT
Cache-Control: public; max-age=604800
Content-length: 94
Connection: close

However, performing the same request to the nginx proxy:
root@appserver [/etc/nginx/sites-enabled] # curl -I http://localhost:5555/service-worker.js
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2024 05:54:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Security-Policy: default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'

We get that 404 error. This error occurs for all resources: fonts, css, images, javascript, and so forth.
The _general.conf file contains the following:
#set_real_ip_from 10.2.46.0/24;
#real_ip_header proxy_protocol;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;

# . files

#location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
#       try_files $uri /dev/null =404;
#}

location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
}

# assets, media
location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
}

# svg, fonts
location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires 7d;
        access_log off;
}

# gzip rules
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

I am stumped - it seems as though nginx is looking for the assets locally instead of proxy_passing them to the upstream server. If that is the case, how do I make it pass all the requests to the upstream server?
